# Is there an easier way to change the head of a branchname

Tags: git, git-branch

I have a scenario where I'm on a branch (fx `develop`), but there's another branch that should be called `develop` instead of current. Going from:

```
  B -- C 
 /
A -- D  (develop)
```

to:

```
  B -- C (develop)
 /
A -- D
```

Of course there's a way to do this:

```
git branch -d develop
git checkout OTHER_HEAD
git checkout -b develop
```

the question is if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem to be a way to do this directly (reset the branch name). If you only want to reset the branch name use

```
git branch -f develop OTHER_HEAD
```

if you also want to check out the other branch you'll use

```
git checkout -B develop OTHER_HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to rename both branches directly -

```
git branch -m develop current
git branch -m other_branch develop
```